# CSS não carrega com link

Tags: php, css

Olá, estou fazendo um login e preciso passar o usuário logado para outras páginas.

Chamo a outra página desta forma:

```
$url = 'cadastroFuncionario.php/nome='.$nome.'&id='.$idFuncionario.'';
```

Porém esta página (`cadastroFuncionario`) não carrega o css.
Há outro jeito de passar o funcionário logado para as outras páginas?

O meu código:

```
if ((isset($_POST["id"])) && (isset($_POST["senha"]))) {
    $idFuncionario = $_POST["id"];
    $senha = $_POST["senha"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM funcionario WHERE id = '$idFuncionario' AND senha LIKE '$senha' ";
    $q = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
        $nome = $registro["nome"];
    }

    if (is_null($nome)){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.alert('Usuario ou senha incorretos') </script>";
    } else {
        $url = "cadastroFuncionario.php/nome=" . $nome . "&id=" . $idFuncionario . "";
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL=' . $url . '">';
    }
```

Comment: Quando chamo aquele link ele não carrega o CSS. Aparece só a página sem formatação. Tb não sei se estou passando o funcionário do correto

Answer (score -1):

use o seguinte exemplo:

```
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="../index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Repare no `../` , Talvez o arquivo está acima do ficheiro da folha de estilos.

Comment: Se eu fizer isso nenhuma página mostra o css

Comment: Então @paloma tente usar o `header('Location: página.php'); ` para redirecionamento